# 404 on script with node, koa, webpack and react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, koa

I'm trying to use https://github.com/CrocoDillon/universal-react-redux-boilerplate to start a proyect but I have a weird error.

When I run the npm run dev command, the example "works". It displays the web at localhost:3000 but

```
<script src="/app.js"></script>
```

gets a 404 and doesn't load.

The weird starts when I right click it and click "open link in new tab"... I takes me to localhost:3000/app.js and there is the script!!!

I'm not very familiar with node and I don't understand whats happening.

If I run the app in production mode it works fine so I think the problemn must be related to webpack or hot reload... Maybe here -> https://github.com/CrocoDillon/universal-react-redux-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack.server.js But I don't fully understand whats happening in this code.

Any help or clue to fix it? I don't want to open an issue in the repo or something without being sure that the error is not my fault.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also don't understand what's happening in that code, but I think has nothing to do with the 404 error

The problem probably comes that, in node,as a different from a standard (ie Apache) webserver, **the only  routes that exist are the ones  that you explicitly declare** .

So can't help you too much without seeing  your koa routing, but I'll bet that probably you haven't declared a route that includes '**/app.js**'. That's why you get a 404 even when the file exists

Comment: The point is that I don't just get a 404, I get a 404 when I try to load the script in html, but if I go to the route in the browser (chrome) I can see the raw script, so is not a 404...

Comment: I'm using the repo "as it is", the server file is https://github.com/CrocoDillon/universal-react-redux-boilerplate/blob/master/src/index.js